# How to add a button to a partial which closes the partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this partial

_reply.haml

```
.reply-form
    = form_for comment, :remote => true do |f|
        = f.text_area :body, :input_html => { :rows => "2" }, :label => false
        = f.text_field :commentable_id, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_id
        = f.text_field :commentable_type, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_type
        = f.text_field :p_comment, :as => :hidden, :value => parent_comment.id
        = f.submit "Reply!", :class => "btn btn-primary", :disable_with => "Submitting…"
```

I need to add a 'Cancel' button which will remove the partial from the page (Hide and remove). The _reply.haml partial is not loaded when the page loads. It loads when someone clicks "Reply" on a comment.

I tried adding `= button_tag 'Cancel', :id => "cancel_button", :remote => true` to the end of _reply.haml but it ended up going through the create action of the Comments controller for some reason. (If you click reply, it will go to the create action of the comments controller - this is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you just need to remove the reply form which can be done using a simple js code by adding:

```
= button_tag 'Cancel', :id => "cancel_button"
```

As you added the above, to remove the `div` from `DOM` you don't need to send a `AJAX` request. You can just add a `js` code:

```
$("#cancel_button").click(function(){
  $(".reply-form").remove();
});
```

So when you will click again on reply the `AJAX` will be fired and the partial will be loaded again in `DOM`.

Hope this helps.